# How do I extend the timeout for a Web Service in Silverlight 2.0?

Tags: silverlight, web-services

I am reading from a .NET 2.0 web service using Silverlight 2.0. The web service requests time out after 30 seconds, which is OK for most queries but occasionally I get a timeout. How do I extend the timeout to one minute?

I tried this but it makes no difference.

```
    SilverSearchSoapClient client = new SilverSearchSoapClient();
    client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(App.ServiceEndpointUrl);
    client.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    client.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    return client;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
```